# Trying to make code more efficient but it doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm not great with JavaScript but I'm trying to learn.  I have all of these functions that work separately, but it's ugly and repetitive.  I try to clean it up and in my brain it looks like it should work but it doesn't.  It also doesn't really look like other code I've seen so I'm guessing I did it very wrong.  What did I do?

Original mess:

```
function resizeHeaderOnScroll() {
  const distanceY = window.pageYOffset || 
  document.documentElement.scrollTop,
  shrinkOn = 200,
  headerEl = document.getElementById('header');

  if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
    headerEl.classList.add('smaller');
  } else {
    headerEl.classList.remove('smaller');
  }
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', resizeHeaderOnScroll);


function resizeMarginOnScroll() {
  const distanceY = window.pageYOffset || 
  document.documentElement.scrollTop,
  shrinkOn = 200,
  aboutEl = document.getElementById('about');

  if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
    aboutEl.classList.add('smaller-about');
  } else {
    aboutEl.classList.remove('smaller-about');
  }
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', resizeMarginOnScroll);


function toggleNavOnScroll() {
  const distanceY = window.pageYOffset || 
  document.documentElement.scrollTop,
  shrinkOn = 200,
  navEl = document.getElementById('nav');

  if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
    navEl.classList.add('toggle-nav');
  } else {
    navEl.classList.remove('toggle-nav');
  }
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', toggleNavOnScroll);


function toggleLandingContentOnScroll() {
  const distanceY = window.pageYOffset || 
  document.documentElement.scrollTop,
  shrinkOn = 200;

  if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
    document.getElementById('landing-full').style.display= 'none';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('landing-full').style.display= 'block';
  }
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', toggleLandingContentOnScroll);
```

Attempt at cleaning it up:

```
function resizeHeaderOnScroll() {
  const distanceY = window.pageYOffset || 
  document.documentElement.scrollTop,
  shrinkOn = 200,
  headerEl = document.getElementById('header'),
  aboutEl = document.getElementById('about'),
  navEl = document.getElementById('nav');

  if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
    headerEl.classList.add('smaller');
    aboutEl.classList.add('smaller-about');
    navEl.classList.add('toggle-nav');
    document.getElementById('landing-full').style.display= 'none';
  } else {
    headerEl.classList.remove('smaller');
    aboutEl.classList.remove('smaller-about');
    navEl.classList.remove('toggle-nav');
    document.getElementById('landing-full').style.display= 'block';
  }
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', resizeHeaderOnScroll);
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in console?

Comment: Please help us troubleshoot this by putting all the HTML/CSS/JS into the editor (_document icon that has `<>`_)

Comment: What doesn't work?  Are there any errors?

Comment: Well this is embarrassing.  First time I braved asking a question in four years and of course the moment I go to grab the errors I saw earlier magically it works.  I've been sitting here adjusting it using the old way, just now commented that out and added the clean way again and now it's good to go.  There must've been something wonky in script.js that I inadvertently got rid of that now makes it function correctly. Or maybe it was something to do with the classes I toggled. 
 So sorry, and thanks for all of the quick responses.